# Sharepoint 2010: Cannot search items in document library unless is the System Account

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library

I have the following problem. I made a site collection with some document libraries. The default template put a field called "Search this site.." on the main page, which if I use the System Account works as it should, but when I'm logged in as a regular user it is not returning any search results.

I checked in the Library Advanced Settings and the "Allow items from this document library to appear in search results?" feature is turned on.

Also, the users are able to download these documents, so I don't know why they are not able to search for them unless it is the System Account.

EDIT: I had to change the server name because I was using an image for my development virtual machine where the server had the name of another machine on the network, I never experienced any problem with it, but this may be side effect of it.

Comment: When it works as SysAcct, do the URLs reflect the new server name or the old one? Are you looking at old search results? Maybe kick off a full crawl and see if it errors or resolves the issue.

Comment: Are your search and crawl accounts domain accounts? I once had the same problem when I had set up crawling using a local account.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have some error in logs ?

I had following error:

AuthzInitializeContextFromSid failed with ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED. This error indicates that the account under which this process is executing may not have read access to the tokenGroupsGlobalAndUniversal attribute on the querying user's Active Directory object. Query results which require non-Claims Windows authorization will not be returned to this querying user.

And only user with admin right could see the results. You can find solution for this issue here - http://www.kanwalkhipple.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=28#waagroup

Answer (score 1):

The effected libraries had the option Library Settings > Versioning Settings > Draft item security set to 'Only users who can edit items'.

Change the above option to 'Any user who can read items' then reset the index and do a full crawl, the documents where indexed and are now being served up by search.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what do you mean, you need to show your custom column in the search core results.
To do that I suggest to you add your column in the searchable content.

I wrote this post, it's in italian but is easy to follow: http://salvatoredifaziosharepoint.blogspot.it/2010/09/aggiungere-un-campo-nei-risultati-di.html